# Customer Analysis - How to handle unbalanced data?

Tags: python, statistics, analytics

I'm taking a data analysis course and decided to work on a customer analysis project. In the data, I have three countries:

USA (539 unique users)
BRA(385 unique users)
TUR (129 unique users)

I'm trying to analyze the country that brings in the most income, so I've decided to look at the mean revenue for each country. However when I do that I get the following result:

[image]

I've done an ANOVA test to compare the means, and the result was that I'd fail to reject the null hypothesis.(p-value 0.449733).

It's not possible for Turkey to generate the most mean, because it has the lowest number of users and the lowest sum. I think it's showing the highest mean because the denominator when calculating the average is small.

In a real world scenario, how would you go about plotting and explainng that its USA that's generating the most income. Should I randomly sample equal data from each country and then calculate the mean? Or was the average revenue the wrong metric to look at?

I'd really appreciate any pointers you could give or direction on how this would be solved in a real scenario. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Why would it be impossible for the Turkey to have the largest mean? If you only have 1 user in XXX country, who is spending 10k, the total for XXX country will be 10k (the minimum), the number of user will be 1 (the minimum), but the average spending will be 10k (the largest). Or is there something I missed here? Could you explain what is the data in your table and the relationship between them? Additionally, why not simply taking the sum if what you want is to demonstrate that the USA are generating the most income?

Comment: The data I'm working with shows each customer in each country and how much they spent. I'm trying to learn what I applied and so from my understanding, the reason why Turkey isn't the country to generate the most amount, is because when looking at the SUM, it's clear that USA is generating more. But most papers I've read say to take the mean as the measure when working with revenue.

Comment: You need to see which criteria make sense first! You will often find yourself in situations where you'd want to know which users spend the most (to choose where to expand activity, for instance). In this case, you will check the locations where the users are spending the most (the largest mean). In some other instances, you could need to temporarily interrupt service in a country, and thus choose to do it in the country that makes the least in total revenue (the smallest sum). These are examples, but for more precise advice, you'd need to provide more context with regards to your objective.

Comment: Again, the mean and the sum are not equivalent, for there is another variable: the number of users.